# Grub menu like program

Tags: centos, grub

I want to make a c program for CentOS with a graphical menu like the Grub menu.

I tried to understand the grub source code, but I can't figure out how to get only the menu part.

Is there any sample that just displays an options menu with a background image?

[image: Redhat grub menu]

Comment: Grub is a bootloader so that is a bit difficult to program, is that what you want to do or do you want to have a text based menu with a background image? That is, it looks like grub but works inside Linux and not as a bootloader? The difference is that inside Linux you have access to many more libraries then when doing a bootloader.

Comment: Yes indeed, Grub is complicated, I have started with a solution combining ncurses with framebuffer image viewer, but I was wondering if there is a ready to use source code, otherwise I have to write my own.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a *text based user interface* there is pretty much only 1 option [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) .

There are also other libraries built on top of `ncurses` like `dialog` or `CDK`

http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html

http://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html

( just use an image search engine if you want examples about what kind of interfaces you can build with it )

Comment: I already build an ncurses program, but I can't put a background image (png/jpg) with ncurses because it's just a text UI.

Comment: @GenErike infact I don't you can do it, you can fill a background with a color, ncurses let's you do just that, but nothing more . The most "artistic" thing you can do is something like ASCII art or just use `banner` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_(Unix) . But banner is not standard and/or not available on all linux / unix machines, usually it's not that popular, it's usually packaged in a repo somewhere but not installed by default .

Comment: there is also Plymouth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_(software) that is probably the fanciest thing ever on linux, better than the initial GRUB menu, but the main problem is that a shell doesn't really give you access to nothing more than basic colors and solid characters ... you can probably dig deeper in the Plymouth codebase if you really want to do this you will probably find an answer there .

Comment: I forget about plymouth, thanks for reminding me. I'll give it a try.